# Closed subsets of Lindelöf spaces are Lindelöf

Tags: general-topology, compactness, lindelof-spaces

Let $X$ be Lindelöf and let $A \subseteq X$ be closed. Show that it follows that $A$ is Lindelöf.

That is, we want to show for every open cover of $A$, there is a countable subcover.

**Note: (A space is Lindelöf if every open cover of the space has a countable subcover, a *weakening* of the better-known notion of compactess).**

Comment: Hmm... Do you remember how to prove that a closed subset of a compact space is compact?

Comment: Let *U* be an open cover of A. Since all elements of U are open, they are equal to the intersection of some family of open sets with A. Let this collection of intersections be denoted V.

Comment: Then consider open cover of *X*, which consists of X-A and V. Since X is Lindelof, then the union of X-A and V has a countable subcover...

Comment: Ah, then take away X-A, then V would still be countable, leaving only the desired countable cover of A.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Using DeMorgan's laws, one can show that a space $X$ is Lindelof iff for every collection $A_\alpha$ of closed subsets of $X$ with the countable intersection property (meaning the intersection of any countable subcollection is nonempty), the total intersection $\cap A_\alpha$ is nonempty.  If $A \subset X $ is closed, then every closed set in $A$ is also closed in $X$ so by the previous characterization of Lindelof, $A$ must be Lindelof.

Comment: Very cool, Seth. Thanks.

Answer (score 11):

Let $C$ be a  cover of $A$.  Since $A$ is closed, $A^C$, the complement of $A$, is open.  Then $C\cup\bigl\{A^C\bigr\}$ is an open  cover of $X$.  It contains a countable subcover $C'$.  Then $C'\setminus\bigl\{A^C\bigr\}$ is countable, covers $A$, and is a subcover of $C$.